# MVVM binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I am trying to map my data to chart from ViewModel. I set bindings, populating object but for some reason no data is displayed. Could you please validate what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

View Model File:

```
QueryableCollectionView qcv;
public QueryableCollectionView Groups
{
    get
    {
        return qcv;
    }
    set
    {
        qcv = value;
    }

}

public RevenueChartViewModel()
{

    List<Revenue> list = new List<Revenue>
    {
        new Revenue{Rev = 10, Category = 1, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)},
        new Revenue{Rev = 20, Category = 1, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3)},
        new Revenue{Rev = 30, Category = 2, Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(6)},
    };

    qcv = new QueryableCollectionView(list);
    qcv.GroupDescriptors.Add(new GroupDescriptor() { Member = "Category" });
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FrontEnd.RevenueChart"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrontEnd"
             mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          xmlns:telerikChart="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting"
             xmlns:telerikCharting="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting"
             xmlns:telerikControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:RevenueChartViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <telerikChart:RadChart x:Name="radChart1">
            <telerik:Series DataSeries="{Binding Groups}">

            </telerik:Series>
            <telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
                <telerikCharting:SeriesMapping LegendLabel="Product Sales">
                    <telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                        <telerikCharting:AreaSeriesDefinition/>
                    </telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
                    <telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
                        <telerikCharting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XCategory" FieldName="Date"/>
                        <telerikCharting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="Rev"/>
                    </telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
                </telerikCharting:SeriesMapping>
            </telerik:RadChart.SeriesMappings>
        </telerikChart:RadChart>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You're not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your view model and you need to set the DataContext of view.

Comment: Thanks Chris, what do you mean by set DataContext of view? is it necessary to have INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the data updating, in the case you are just displaying data from somewhere else, I would suggest just moving the datacontext initialization into the constructor, this will happen after the view is ready and it will retrieve your groups without having to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Its likely even if the collection needs to change that this is plenty good because the Collection will fire a CollectionChanged event once the binding is set.